# Git Commands using powershell

Tags: git, powershell

how to make the default directory of git as the location of the current powershell script

this is the content of **git-init.ps1**

at ***C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/Project101/git-init.ps1***

and i want to initialize this path ***C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/Project101/***

but the problem is the git will initialize this path ***c:/Users/MyUser/.git*** i just followed the commands from Git Bash

any help would be aprreciated. TIA

```
function run-git
{
    # location of my installed git
    $x = Get-ChildItem env:LOCALAPPDATA | %{ $_.Value }
    $y = $x + "\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe"

    # .$y --login -i -c "git init"
    # .$y --login -i -c "git remote add -t 'master' 'origin' 'E:/ProjectRepository/Project101'"
    # .$y --login -i -c "git pull"

    # get the location of this script
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    $p = Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path

    .$y --login -i -c "cd $p"
    .$y --login -i -c "git init"
    # .$y --login -i -c "git init 'E:/WorkingDirectory'"
    .$y --login -i -c "git status"
}

run-git;
```

Comment: why not just use posh-git?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you do a line like this:

```
.$y --login -i -c "cd $p"
```

You are running the shell, changing the directory, then exiting the shell. The new location is lost.

I would recommend using

```
Push-Location $p

# Do git commands here, remember that git spews verbose on stderr and causes powershell to barf

Pop-Location
```

The other option is to use `git --work-tree="$p"` or something similar, but that way lies madness.